# Apply migrations in MySQL docker container. Can't find database

Tags: python, mysql, docker, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am using alembic and sqlalchemy to migrate the database.

The container is running and working, as I am able to use phpmyadmin to apply manual changes.

Using `alembic upgrade head` locally in my virtual environment works and updates the database living in the docker container.

But when trying to automate the execution of the command, I run into issues.

When trying to put it into the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11 

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r ./requirements.txt

RUN alembic upgrade head

COPY  . /app

EXPOSE 8002:8002

CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

It spits out `alembic: not found` when running `docker compose up --build`.

When trying to run the command from the docker compose file:

```yaml
services:
  vsync-backend:
    container_name: vsync-backend
    build:
      context: /backend/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8002:8002
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    command: bash -c "alembic upgrade head && python app/main.py"

  vsync-frontend:
    container_name: vsync-frontend
    build:
      context: /frontend/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - vsync-backend
    networks:
      - vsync-authentication
  
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=vsync
    networks:
      - vsync-authentication

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    restart: always
    networks:
      - vsync-authentication

networks:
  vsync-authentication:

volumes:
  mysql:
```

This gives me the error `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)") (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)`

To test if it would even work, I tried running the upgrade command in the container itself.

Same error.

I checked the connection string (`mysql+mysqldb://root:root@localhost:3306/vsync`), replaced the host (with and without port) with the mysql container name. But to no avail.

How do I fix automatically applying the migrations to the database?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

My `vsync-backend` was not on the same network.

I spent too much time on this.

I'll go cry now.

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself. We've all had a oh doh, moment. Just adopt the belief you've learnt from it and you'll be fine :-)